# Multiple Positions of one div

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div named "pos". I have 3 pages like index.php, register.php and login.php. I have defined the div property in css file and it working fine as per the content of each page. But in index page i want the same div to be displayed in little bit top. so what should i do to define the div property in the index page?

```
#po
{ 
  margin-top: 12em; margin-bottom: 1.8em;
}
```

Comment: you dont have any code?

Comment: #po{
 margin-top: 12em;
 margin-bottom: 1.8em;
}

Comment: @ZachSaucier HOw do i define the property of same div which is already defined in the css file?

Comment: in the index page wrap the content with a div with an id of something different like `id="home"` then target that div specifically: `#home #pos` overwrites default `#pos`

Comment: you can also add a class to that div, this way you could use it more often

Comment: Why not just switch to using classes. Then you can do `<div class="pos pos--margin"></div>` You want to try and make your `CSS` as re-usable as possible.

Comment: @ChandraSekharBiswal Did you end up solving your issue?

Answer (score 3):

If you want custom styles for one page, then in the HTML for that page you can either define a custom style in some `<style>` tags in the head or include a custom stylesheet in the head

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customstylesheet.css">

<style> /* This is recommended as opposed to using a separate stylesheet */
    #pos {
        /* Your new styles */
    }
</style>
</head>
```

This way you can avoid adding more classes and it reduces confusion on pages where the class is not found but the same stylesheet is used

Comment: +1 bcoz it helps reduce the bloat on common css especially for those one-time or page-specific classes. (oth: sometimes keeping one-time cases in common css may actually help keep the context.)

Answer (score 3):

You could add a `index` class to the `html` tag in index.php, and then in your css add the property like `.index #pos{values}`

```
<html class="index">
```

Or you could add the `index` class to the same div and call it like `#pos.index{values}` in your css.

```
<div id="pos" class="index">
```

Comment: where to write m not getting plz elaborate

Answer (score 1):

Set a id or class on the body of the index page

Normal

```
 .po{
    /* your style */
    }
```

Index Page

```
<body class="poindex">


body.poindex .po{
     /* your style */
}
```